# How to execute some database commands in koa before or after app.listen()

Tags: mysql, koa

## Desired outcome

I want to check the state of the database on or around the startup of my node + koa + mysql server and apply update scripts if needed.

## Optimal flow in server.js

1. Set up MySQL connection
2. Check and update the database

   - Crash and burn if there is an issue with the update scripts or an unexpected error in the updating process.
3. Add Routes
4. Start Server

I figure the updating of the database can be done at any point after #1, but I haven't been too successful yet.

I'm basing my work heavily on the example code from https://github.com/chrisveness/koa-sample-web-app-api-mysql, though it's simpler in regards to only focusing on the api.

## Code snippets

```
// schema/fate2.js
const versionModel = require('../models/version');
module.exports = function* updateToHead() {
  yield versionModel.init();
  try {
    yield syncTrunkAndDev();
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("Latest trunk schema version is: " + versionModel.getTrunkLast());
    console.log("Latest dev schema version is: " + versionModel.getDevLast());
    throw "Error in upgrading", e;
  }
}

// server.js
app.use(require('./schema/fate2'));
...
app.listen(process.env.PORT||3030);

// models/version.js
const Version = module.exports = {};

Version.init = function*() {
  yield GLOBAL.db.query(
  "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS version ( " +
    " id int(11) NOT NULL," +
    " dev int(1) NOT NULL," +
    " description varchar(50) NOT NULL," +
    " applied_on timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP," +
    " dirty int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1'," +
    " PRIMARY KEY (id)" +
  ") ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8"
  );
};
```

## Other stackoverflow posts

[How to perform initial setup in koa with rethinkdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32851452/how-to-perform-initial-setup-in-koa-with-rethinkdb)
- I read this one and tried it but it didn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The process of solving the problem was correct, but after significant digging, the root of the problem was caused by incorrect calling of generator functions.

See [Javascript strange generator yield sub function behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34253463/javascript-strange-generator-yield-sub-function-behavior)

Answer (score 1):

Simplest solution might be to wrap your `app.listen` in a `co` process so that you can sequentially yield your start-up procedures before you boot the server.

If any of them throw, then execution will skip `app.listen` and you can easily catch all exceptions in one place:

```
const co = require('co');

co(function*() {
  yield require('./schema/fate2');
  yield require('./models/version').init();
  app.listen(3000, function() { console.log('listening on 3000') });
}).catch(function(err) {
  console.error('Server boot failed:', err, err.stack);
});
```

I've also stumbled upon https://github.com/node-modules/ready-callback before on Github, but have nothing further to say about it.