# Javascript strange generator yield sub function behavior

Tags: javascript, mysql, generator, ecmascript-6, yield

I'm using MySQL (`mysql-co`) and ASQ(`asynquence`) in a simple project to get a better understanding of ES6 generators and yield functions, and I'm stumped on an odd behavior.

#### Short explanation of `asynquence`

`asynquence` (https://github.com/getify/asynquence) provides an easy way for me to run generators in sequence. It can also do pseudo-parallel execution but that's not what I need for now.  The structure of `function *x(token)` is from there.  `token` holds a connection object at `[0]`. `yield token` passes control on to the next generator function in sequence.

### Code Sample 1 (works)

```
function *test1(token) {
  var conn = token.messages[0];
  var values = {id:1, dev:1, description:'This is it!'};
  yield conn.query("INSERT INTO version SET ?", values);
  yield token;
}
```

This works fine. The row described above gets inserted. I didn't know the MySQL driver allowed such a simple looking insert function but it does.

### Code Sample 2 (doesn't work)

```
function *test1(token) {
  var conn = token.messages[0];
  var values = {id:1, dev:1, description:'This is it!'};
  yield subtest1(conn, values);
  yield token;
}
function *subtest1(conn, values) {
  yield conn.query("INSERT INTO version SET ?", values);
}
```

This doesn't work. The actual code in question for subtest1 is in a model class, so I would prefer not to have it merged in with the controller.

I've tried a bunch of different things around with or without yield on the subtest function.

What's going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`subtest1(conn, values)` is a generator. `yield`ing a generator object does not execute its body. That is, the yielded generator remains suspended, and it would require a call to the `next()` method for the first `yield` to be reached. There are no explicit or implicit calls to `next()` in *Code Sample 2*, and this is the reason `conn.query(...)` isn't executed.

How about [`yield* subtest1(conn, values)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield*)? From the linked page:

> The `yield*` expression iterates over the operand and yields each value
>   returned by it.

It will still execute `subtest` lazily.

An alternative solution is to turn `subtest` into a regular function and return the result of `conn.query(...)` (assuming you only need to perform one query):

```
function subtest1(conn, values) {
    return conn.query("INSERT INTO version SET ?", values);
}
```

Comment: *"`yield`ing a generator object does not start its execution"* Tricky phrasing there. It *does* start it, in that it calls the function and gets back the iterator. It's just that it doesn't then iterate through what it gets back, it just yields that actual iterator object for the current iteration of `test1`. (+1 though)

Answer (score 3):

`yield subtest1(conn, values)` calls `subtest1(conn, values)`, which returns an iterator object, and then yields that from `test1` as the value for that iteration of `test1`. It doesn't *iterate* the values returned by the `subtest1` iterator.

You *could* have `test1` iterate the values from `subtest1`'s iterator by adding a `*` after the `yield`:

```
yield* subtest1(conn, values);
```

but looking at your code, I don't think you want to. If you want to split the `conn.query` line out into a function, it would look like this:

```
function *test1(token) {
  var conn = token.messages[0];
  var values = {id:1, dev:1, description:'This is it!'};
  yield subtest1(conn, values);
  yield token;
}
function subtest1(conn, values) {
  return conn.query("INSERT INTO version SET ?", values);
}
```

This simpler version may help with the difference between `yield` and `yield*`:

```
function* foo() {
  console.log("f");
  yield bar();
  console.log("f done");
}
function* bar() {
  console.log("b1");
  let i = 0;
  while (i < 3) {
    console.log("b2");
    yield i;
    ++i;
  }
  console.log("b done");
}
for (let v of foo()) {
  console.log(v);
}
```

The output of that is: ([live copy on Babel's REPL](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=false&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=true&code=function*%20foo()%20%7B%0A%20%20console.log(%22f%22)%3B%0A%20%20yield%20bar()%3B%0A%20%20console.log(%22f%20done%22)%3B%0A%7D%0Afunction*%20bar()%20%7B%0A%20%20console.log(%22b1%22)%3B%0A%20%20let%20i%20%3D%200%3B%0A%20%20while%20(i%20%3C%203)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(%22b2%22)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20yield%20i%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%2B%2Bi%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20console.log(%22b%20done%22)%3B%0A%7D%0Afor%20(let%20v%20of%20foo())%20%7B%0A%20%20console.log(v)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A))

```
f
{}
f done
```

Note how we don't see any of the "b" logging at all; that's because the `{}` you see after `f1` is the iterator object returned by calling `bar`.

If we just add `*` on the `yield bar();` line, turning it into `yield* bar()`, the output changes: (live copy)

```
f
b1
b2
0
b2
1
b2
2
b done
f done
```

If the operand to `yield*` is an iterator, `yield*` iterates it, `yield`ing each of its values. It's basically:

```
for (value of bar()) {
    yield value;
}
```

Comment: The examples you added were excellent in bringing the concept home!